# pg_restore: can't import data if table has a constraint with a function calling another function

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

In PostgreSQL using only `public` schema, data in tables that use in check constraints functions that invoke other functions does not get imported with `pg_restore` after it was dumped with `pg_dump`. But if functions in check constraints do not invoke other functions, data is correctly imported.

I have noted this behavior after minor upgrading from 9.3.22 to 9.3.23 and from 9.4.16 to 9.4.17; in 9.3.22 and 9.4.17 it worked fine.

I understand is due to [changes in search_path](https://bucardo.org/postgres_all_versions.html#version_9.3.22):

> Avoid use of insecure search_path settings in pg_dump and other client
>   programs (Noah Misch, Tom Lane)
>
> pg_dump, pg_upgrade, vacuumdb and other PostgreSQL-provided
>   applications were themselves vulnerable to the type of hijacking
>   described in the previous changelog entry; since these applications
>   are commonly run by superusers, they present particularly attractive
>   targets. To make them secure whether or not the installation as a
>   whole has been secured, modify them to include only the pg_catalog
>   schema in their search_path settings. Autovacuum worker processes now
>   do the same, as well.
>
> In cases where user-provided functions are indirectly executed by
>   these programs — for example, user-provided functions in index
>   expressions — the tighter search_path may result in errors, which will
>   need to be corrected by adjusting those user-provided functions to not
>   assume anything about what search path they are invoked under. That
>   has always been good practice, but now it will be necessary for
>   correct behavior. (CVE-2018-1058 or CVE-2018-1058)

Still it's unclear to me why having one level public functions is allowed but it is not those functions to invoke other ones.

For example, having this structure and data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_even(n integer) RETURNS boolean AS $BODY$ 
BEGIN
  return n%2 = 0;  
END ; $BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_even_positive(n integer) RETURNS boolean AS $BODY$ 
BEGIN
  return is_even(n) and n > 0;  
END ; $BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TABLE test_check (
  n integer
  CONSTRAINT even_chk CHECK (is_even(n)));

CREATE TABLE test_check2(
  n integer
  CONSTRAINT even_positive_chk CHECK (is_even_positive(n)));

insert into test_check values (2);
insert into test_check values (-2);
insert into test_check2 values (2);
```

Exporting it with:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432  -F c -b -v -f test.dmp test -U test
```

And importing it in a new database:

```
$ pg_restore -d test2 -U test -v test.dmp -h localhost
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: creating SCHEMA "public"
pg_restore: creating COMMENT "SCHEMA public"
pg_restore: creating EXTENSION "plpgsql"
pg_restore: creating COMMENT "EXTENSION plpgsql"
pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.is_even(integer)"
pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.is_even_positive(integer)"
pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.test_check"
pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.test_check2"
pg_restore: processing data for table "public.test_check"
pg_restore: processing data for table "public.test_check2"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2035; 0 7784774 TABLE DATA test_check2 tad
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "test_check2": ERROR:  function is_even(integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT is_even(n) and n > 0
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT is_even(n) and n > 0
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function public.is_even_positive(integer) line 3 at RETURN
COPY test_check2, line 1: "2"
pg_restore: creating ACL "SCHEMA public"
WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 1
```

Note `test_check` table gets correctly imported with data whereas `test_check2` fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to explicitly set a `search_path` for the functions.

Then it won't matter that `pg_restore` sets `search_path = pg_catalog`, bacause it will be overridden by the function's setting.

This will also protect the functions from inadvertedly picking up functions and operators from a different schema that happens to be set in the calling session (which is the security problem the change is trying to fix).

```
ALTER FUNCTION is_even_(integer) SET search_path=public;
ALTER FUNCTION is_even_positive(integer) SET search_path=public;
```

Comment: More information in PostgreSQL [pgsql-bugs list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/152153826367.11956.8092048336300020216%40wrigleys.postgresql.org)

Comment: Another related [thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/152106914669.1223.5104148605998271987%40wrigleys.postgresql.org#152106914669.1223.5104148605998271987@wrigleys.postgresql.org)